# Forms Authentication Cookie Not Persisting on Server But does on LocalHost

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, forms-authentication, persistent

I have been working on a web application that is setup on IIS 7 as one of several applications and web services operating under the DefaultWebSite.  When developing on localhost, my FormsAuthentication cookie persists; however, when published on the server the cookie(s) are not persistent.  I am using SQLServer sessions, and have validation keys in the web config to rule out application pool recycling.  I have been trying to figure this out for a while now with no luck...please help!

Here is some code below:

```
<forms name=".OPTFORMSTEST" loginUrl="~/Secure/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx"  timeout="240" path="/" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All" />

Public Shared Function DoLogin(ByVal strUsername As String, ByVal isPersistent As Boolean)
    Dim authTicket As FormsAuthenticationTicket
    Dim authCookie As HttpCookie
    Dim strUserData As String = strUsername
    Dim intTimeoutPersist As Integer = 43200    '(30 days)
    Dim intTimeoutNonPersist As Integer = 300   '(5 hours)
    Dim intRtn As Integer = 1
    Dim strCookiePath As String = Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Remove(Current.Request.ApplicationPath.Length)

    Try
        'set cookie timout period and create auth ticket based on isPersistent
        If isPersistent Then
            'create a persistent ticket
            authTicket = New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, strUsername, _
                DateTime.Now(), _
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(intTimeoutPersist), _
                True, strUserData)
        Else
            'create a temp ticket
            authTicket = New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, strUsername, _
                DateTime.Now(), _
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(intTimeoutNonPersist), _
                False, strUserData)
        End If

        'create encrypted string for user data
        Dim strEncr As String = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket)
        'create cookie
        authCookie = New HttpCookie("OPTFORMSTEST", strEncr)
        'set cookie expiration based on the auth ticket
        If isPersistent Then
            authCookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration
        End If
        Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie)
    Catch ex As Exception
        intRtn = -1
    End Try
    Return intRtn
End Function
```

Comment: FYI: You can check the actual cookies by using this "Edit this Cookie" extension on Chrome.  Check the expiration to get more information.

Comment: Cookie expiration on LocalHost is 22/03/2013 12:58 PM (30 days), but the cookie on the production site expires on 26/02/2013 04:36 PM (4 hours from the login time). 4 hours matches the timeout value specified in web.config.  It seems like the persistent expiration is being ignored.

Comment: Seems like an issue with your web.config file on the production box.  Are you using web.config transforms? like web.debug.config and web.release.config?

Comment: I am not using any web.config transforms.  In fact, the only difference between the local and production config files are the CustomErrors and compilation tags.

Comment: It looks like your else loop with 4 hours is being executed are u passing the false as your isPersistent variable value in the DoLogin Method?

Comment: I am passing the value of Checked for the "Keep me logged in" check box on the login page of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, I found out that the RedirectFromLoginPage method was creating another cookie when used from the production box.  I replaced with a Response.Redirect and only one cookie was created and it was persistent.